# Display lines as percentage in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I'm making a Chart in Google Charts and I'm trying to make the lines display by their change in percentage pretty much, so you can see the detail in two diffrent lines with very diffrent values. Log scale didn't do the trick.
It currently looks like this with log scale.
So, they would both start at Zero and the following value would be the change in percent from the last point.

[The Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6185.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a calculated column within a `DataView` to plot the "% change"

see following working snippet...

a data table is built with some random numbers for each month in 2016

then a data view is created and the `setColumns` method is used

to hide the original numbers and display a formula for the "% change"

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [new Date('01/01/2016'), 1000],
    [new Date('02/01/2016'), 1200],
    [new Date('03/01/2016'), 1400],
    [new Date('04/01/2016'), 1800],
    [new Date('05/01/2016'), 2600],
    [new Date('06/01/2016'), 5200],
    [new Date('07/01/2016'), 3900],
    [new Date('08/01/2016'), 3100],
    [new Date('09/01/2016'), 1900],
    [new Date('10/01/2016'), 2300],
    [new Date('11/01/2016'), 1200],
    [new Date('12/01/2016'), 1000]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.0%'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, {
    calc: function (dt, r) {
      if ((r === 0) || (dt.getValue(r - 1, 1) === 0)) {
        return null;
      }
      var change = (dt.getValue(r, 1) - dt.getValue(r - 1, 1)) / dt.getValue(r - 1, 1);
      return {
        v: change,
        f: formatNumber.formatValue(change)
      };
    },
    label: '% Change',
    type: 'number'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```